# How to reset chapter after each part

Tags: chapters, parts

How could we reset enumeration after each part? I.e. how can we have part I with chapters 1,2,3 etc, and then part II with chapter 1,2,3 ?

Comment: Usually chapters are numbered sequentially ignoring parts; resetting the numbers would make cross-references to the chapters quite clumsy: “in chapter 3 of part 2 we discussed…”

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
\makeatletter
```

will do what you ask, although it is perhaps more normal to also do

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter{\thepart.\arabic{chapter}}
```

so the chapters are prefixed with the part number, unless the parts are sufficient;y distinct that you never need to cross reference between them.

Comment: Also, if you're using `hyperref` you should use `\@addtoreset` *after* `hyperref` was loaded.