# How to reset ToC section numbering at each part/chapter

Tags: table-of-contents

I am using a pre-made template in overleaf and it includes the following commands in the preamble to control the numbering in the table of contents:

[image]

This results in the following table of contents:

[image]

How would I change it to make the first section of the Context chapter automatically number as 2.1 instead of 2.3?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reset chapter after each part](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123559/how-to-reset-chapter-after-each-part)

Comment: It does, thank you very much! :)